# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

in my controller AuthController/signin i have this code:

```
    entities.UserAccount user = (new BLL.GestionUserAccount()).authentifier(email, password);
            //storing the userId in a cookie
            string roles = (new BLL.GestionUserAccount()).GetUserRoles(user.IdUser);
            // Initialize FormsAuthentication, for what it's worth

            FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

            //

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.IdUser.ToString(), false);

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1, // Ticket version
            user.IdUser.ToString(), // Username associated with ticket
            DateTime.Now, // Date/time issued
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // Date/time to expire
            true, // "true" for a persistent user cookie
            roles, // User-data, in this case the roles
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);// Path cookie valid for

            // Encrypt the cookie using the machine key for secure transport
            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, // Name of auth cookie
               hash); // Hashed ticket



                // Get the stored user-data, in this case, our roles

            // Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
            if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

            // Add the cookie to the list for outgoing response
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
```

in the master page i have a menu ,in that menu there is an item that is meant to be seen only  by admin role.

```
     <% if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")){ %>

            <%=Html.ActionLink("Places", "Places", "Places")%>
        <%} %>
```

even with HttpContext.Current.User conatining the right roles,i can't see the item:

[image]

globalx asax:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                {
                    FormsIdentity id =
                        (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                    // Get the stored user-data, in this case, our roles
                    string userData = ticket.UserData;
                    string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check  if the `Current.User` role principal is properly created?

Comment: gideo ,check the image.my roles are there.

Comment: I know it sounds silly but thats your `userData` from your ticket. The only thing I can think if is if the `userData` is not going into the principal. (Possibly a problem with the last three lines of `glabal.asax`) Just a thought.

Comment: gideon,you are correct.there "admin " coming from my database.trim() has arranged things.Thank you.Should i delete the question?

Comment: haha! Was a wild guess but that't what I thought it was! =) No you don't need to delete the question (Infact you can't) It was a well written question and might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it sounds silly but from your image I can only see your `userData` from your ticket.

The only thing I can think if is if the `userData` is not going into the principal. (Possibly a problem with the last three lines of glabal.asax.cs)

Something is wrong here:

```
string userData = ticket.UserData;
string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `User.IsInRole()`, try the static method `Roles.IsUserInRole()`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom Authorize attribute which will parse the user data portion of the authentication ticket and manually create the IPrincipal. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476355/29407) which illustrates the way I would recommend you to do this in ASP.NET MVC. Never use `HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET MVC application. Not even in your views. Use `<% if (User.IsInRole("admin")) { %>` instead.

Comment: @user594166, I have updated my answer with a link to an example of how I would recommend you proceed in an ASP.NET MVC application: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5476355/29407 It is a much more MVCish way to achieve this.

Comment: in what way it's MVCish? MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute?

Comment: @user594166, it's because in ASP.NET MVC you control authorization using action filters such as the [Authorize] attribute. And ni cases where you need to handle custom authorization as in your case you write a custom authorization attribute. Events in the global.asax such as Application_Request, Application_AuthenticateRequest, ... are used in classic web forms. In ASP.NET MVC there are more native ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One statement is missing.

After this line:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
```

You need to put this line:

```
ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(ticket.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In global.asax assign principal on 2 objects like that:

```
    private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

I found it here [ASP.NET documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, but my cause was two-fold and not addressed by one of the answers listed above.

1. This worked when I was connected to my corporate domain (on-prem or VPN) but not remote
2. I tried adding a local permissions group with a matching name. It didn't help. Later, when I connected to my corporate domain, I was getting this error.  My local permissions group had made things worse.
3. I also tried @OldGeezer's answer, but `Roles.IsUserInRole()` seems to only work with local/forms authentication but not with domain/negotiate/digest.

Solution: If you are using domain/negotiate/digest authentication, confirm that you are connected to your domain (on-prem or vpn), confirm that the group (name) exists (check for spelling mistakes), make sure you don't have a local (pc) group with a conflicting name.