# What are some good static code analysis rules for an ASP.NET MVC Application? (NDepend)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static-analysis, ndepend

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984085/httpcontext-current-user-isinrole-not-working/8984119#8984119) posting where [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) suggested that you never refer to HttpContext.Current in your ASP.NET MVC application.

We have [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com), a tool for doing static code analysis, what are some other rules that you believe would be good to model with something like NDepend?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In our code base (which should reuse existing infrastructure and also uses Autofac for DI) I've currently written some rules along the lines:

- To ensure we are not going to tightly couple ourselves to existing infrastructure
- That we are not using ViewBags in our Views, but instead using ViewModels